# onMessageReceived not called on Mobile

Tags: android, wear-os

I am new to this, but trying to get a v simple example working of sending a message from my Wearable to my Phone. I have read other similar questions, but I can't find the solution amongst the answers I have read.

My problem is the onMessageReceived method in my Listener (running on my Mobile) is never called.

I am using real devices, Sony SmartWatch 3 and Samsung S5

What I have working is

- My wearable sends the message (using Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage) and outputs to the log that the message is successfully sent to the correct node.

What I have tried based on other similar questions I have read :-

- Package in AndroidManifest is same between Mobile and Wearable
- applicationId is same in build.gradle file between Mobile and Wearable
- Uninstalling the apps from both Mobile and Wearable and running apps from Android Studio (**not** in debug mode)

Any guidance very gratefully received, please see my code below.

Thanks

## Mobile Code

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.davidson.anothermessagetest" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".ListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.davidson.anothermessagetest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

### ListenerService

```
package com.davidson.anothermessagetest;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.WearableListenerService;

/**
 * Created by ddavidson on 09/03/2016.
 */
public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        Log.v("myTag", "onMessageReceived:");

        if (messageEvent.getPath().equals("/message_path")) {
            final String message = new String(messageEvent.getData());
            Log.v("myTag", "Message path received on watch is: " + messageEvent.getPath());
            Log.v("myTag", "Message received on watch is: " + message);
        }
        else {
            super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerConnected(Node peer) {
        Log.v("myTag", "onPeerConnected:");
    }
}
```

## Wearable Code

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.davidson.anothermessagetest" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.davidson.anothermessagetest"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
}
```

### MainActivity

```
package com.davidson.anothermessagetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    GoogleApiClient googleClient;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v("myTag", "Wearable: onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        });
        // Build a new GoogleApiClient for the Wearable API
        googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    // Connect to the data layer when the Activity starts
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleClient.connect();
    }

    // Send a message when the data layer connection is successful.
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        String message = "Hello wearable\n Via the data layer";
        //Requires a new thread to avoid blocking the UI
        new SendToDataLayerThread("/message_path", message).start();
    }

    // Disconnect from the data layer when the Activity stops
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (null != googleClient && googleClient.isConnected()) {
            googleClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    // Placeholders for required connection callbacks
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) { }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) { }

    public class SendToDataLayerThread extends Thread {

        String path;
        String message;

        // Constructor to send a message to the data layer
        SendToDataLayerThread(String p, String msg) {
            path = p;
            message = msg;
        }

        public void run() {
            NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleClient).await();
            for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(googleClient, node.getId(), path, message.getBytes()).await();
                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.v("myTag", "Message: {" + message + "} sent to: " + node.getDisplayName());
                }
                else {
                    // Log an error
                    Log.v("myTag", "ERROR: failed to send Message");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.ListenerService`-declaration in your Mobile-`AndroidManifest` must be within the `<application>` tag. In your code it's outside.

Hope this fixes it.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, I've moved the <service> tag inside the <application> tag but don't see any difference. I wonder if I'm looking for the output in the correct place.  I run both apps from  Android Studio (start the Mobile one first) I set the filter on my Studio Window to show the logcat for the Wearable and see the message "03-22 17:13:29.753    6790-6839/? V/myTag﹕ Message: {Hello wearable
    Via the data layer} sent to: David Davidson (Galaxy S5)" then I change the filter to the Mobile, hoping to at least see my onMessageReceived Log message, but that never appears.

Comment: Update - hendra spotted a mistake in my Manifest file, which must have prevented it from working. However after fixing that it still didn't appear to work as I didn't see my message in the logcat, then after poking around, I noticed I had left a search string in the field that filters the logcat, and when I removed that I saw a lot more output (funnily enough!) including my received message. Faceplant moment, but it needed the fix to Manfest to get it working. Anyway I have edited my code now, so that the above code now works. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you should add MESSAGE_RECEIVED action into the manifest.xml rather than BIND_LISTENER or DATA_CHANGED (DATA_CHANGED only used for onDataChange), as for high version of gms e.g. 9.6.1

```
 <service android:name=".MyWearService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*"
                android:path="/sensor_test" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: This actually saved me hours of research. I missed the data tag in my app, otherwise you won't get anything.